# How to write a recursion function in haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I write a function in Haskell which takes a list and a number and it removes all the elements greater than that number and returns the list.

remove [5, 4, 3, 9, 1 ] 5 should return [5,4,3,1]

I wrote the following method which is becoming infinite loop some where when it hits the greater than the given number. I am getting out [5,4,3 and then program is not ending.

```
remove l1 x = if (null l1 == True)
                then l1
                else if (head l1 > x)
                       then remove (drop 0 l1) x
                       else ((head l1) : remove (tail l1) x)
```

This is first time I am trying Haskell programs, please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: You get the infinite loop because `then remove (drop 0 l1) x` you recur on the same list, the first argument of `drop` says how many elements to drop, and you mistyped `drop 0` instead of the `drop 1` you need.

Answer (score 13):

Well, you're off to a decent start, but it's important to note that you are not taking the most "Haskell" approach to this.

Let me show you a few different approaches to this problem:

**Approach 1: Recursive Function**

First and foremost, we *could* write a recursive function (as you are) to solve this.

To do this we first accommodate for a base-case (one that will not, under normal circumstances, allow for an infinite loop). This should work:

```
remove [] _ = []
```

This simply says that if we are to remove elements from an empty list, we end up with an empty list. It's that simple. The `_` means that we don't care what value `x` is.

Now we must define our other cases. For this, I would use guards (I'm sure there are other approaches, base-case added also for completion):

```
remove [] _ = []
remove (x:xs) y
 | x > y     = remove xs y
 | otherwise = x : remove xs y
```

So, the first line (`remove (x:xs) y`) is saying that our function will take a list (where `x` is the head/first value and `xs` is the rest).

The second line is saying that, if `x` is greater than `y`, consider the rest of the elements, and we don't consider `x` to be a part of our final solution.

The third line (`otherwise` catches all cases if hit, and is like an `else` in an `if/elseif/else` conditional block in other languages). If we get to this point, we know that it is not true that `x > y` so we consider the rest of our values (`xs`) and we include `x`, but we're done with `x` for now.

Now, this approach works decently, but there is a simpler one:

**Approach 2: List Comprehensions**

Using [list comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Haskell) we can build a very simple, powerful solution:

```
remove xs y = [x | x <- xs, not (x > y)]
```

If you have ever studied [set-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) (specifically [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation)) this should look oddly familiar to you. Let's walk through what each part means.

- `[...]` - Something in brackets simply means we are constructing a list
- `x |...` - Means that our list will contain `x`s such that (the `|` means "such that")...
- `x <- xs,` - `x` is an element of `xs` and (the comma means "and")...
- `not (y > x)` - It is not true that `y` is greater than `x`

As you can see, this second approach almost exactly imitates your problem's description. This is truly the power of Haskell, words and abstraction tend to, nearly, map directly into Haskell code.

**Approach 3: Using `filter`**

As the below comment states a third alternative would be to define it as such:

```
remove y = filter (<=y)
```

Where filter will only keep elements that are less than or equal to y. (Credit to Daniel Wagner for this approach).

Comment: ...or  just `remove y = filter (<=y)`.

Comment: Yes, good point. I saw another answer saying that and gave them +1.

Answer (score 7):

You can use pattern matching in function args and filter with guards:

```
remove []    x = []
remove (h:t) x | h > x = remove t x
               | otherwise = h : remove t x
```

Also you can use function `filter`, it do what you need:

```
remove l x = filter (<= x) l
```